# Java/Parse - The app goes back to the main activity instead of creating new user or signing up

Tags: java, android-studio, parse-platform

I have two buttons on my main screen activity that lead to two different activities, one to login and the other to sign up.

When I'm on the sign in activity or the sign up activity and press the buttons, even when the fields are empty it redirects it to the main screen activity...

For the `signIn` method

```
public void signIn(View View) {
    String username = String.valueOf(this.username.getText());
    String password = String.valueOf(this.password.getText());

    Log.i("SignInInfo", username);
    Log.i("SignInInfo", password);

    ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            if (user != null) {
                // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                Intent userList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserListActivity.class);
                startActivity(userList);
            } else {
                // Signup failed. Look at the ParseException to see what happened.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There was an error with your username/password combination. Please try again...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

For the `signUp` method

```
public void signUp(View View) {
    String firstname = String.valueOf(this.firstname.getText());
    String lastname = String.valueOf(this.lastname.getText());
    String username = String.valueOf(this.username.getText());
    String password = String.valueOf(this.password.getText());
    String email = String.valueOf(this.email.getText());

    Log.i("SignUpInfo", "First Name:\t " + firstname);
    Log.i("SignUpInfo", "Last Name:\t " + lastname);
    Log.i("SignUpInfo", "Username:\t " + username);
    Log.i("SignUpInfo", "Password:\t " + password);
    Log.i("SignUpInfo", "Email:\t\t " + email);

    ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();
    newUser.put("First Name", firstname);
    newUser.put("Last Name", lastname);
    newUser.setUsername(username);
    newUser.setPassword(password);
    newUser.setEmail(lastname);

    newUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                Log.i("SignUpInfo", "Sign Up Succesful");
                Intent userList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserListActivity.class);
                startActivity(userList);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome to our cult. Ah, I mean community!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                // Sign up didn't succeed.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage().substring(e.getMessage().indexOf(" ")), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I realized it had something to do with the Parse codes because when I comment the Parse codes for both the log in and sign up it prints the info to the logs, but when I uncomment it, the same issue. It crashes and goes back to the home view...

[image: Navigation Editor View]

Answer (score 0):

When getting a string from an `EditText` it is usually clearer to just write `this.firstname.getText().toString()`.

It is odd that the your log messages only print if your `ParseUser` methods are commented out. Based on your code above they should print either way since the log messages are before parsing.

Looking at the code you shared you might not be properly assigning your `EditText` variables before using them which might cause a crash.

To be sure add the stack trace for the exception that is crashing the app and further help can be given.